# Using Worksheet name VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I was wondering if there any indicator for a worksheet in Excel.
Let's say that I have VBA code that uses Worksheet Name at some point, then I change the name of the worksheet so I need to change this name in my code too. Is there any way to use indicator for a worksheet so I wouldn't have to change this name in my code? Or any other way to use a worksheet in the code without using its name?

Thank you for Your help.

Comment: You can use index too (`Workbook.Worksheets(1)`), but also that can change.

Comment: How about the worksheet's **codename ??**

Comment: Is it the Activesheet?

Comment: You can indeed also use workbook.activesheet to refer to the currently selected sheet. You can use a global variable to store the name of the worksheet in there, and use the global variable in the rest of your code. Would your worksheet's name change, you could edit the macro accordingly at one location.

Comment: You can also use Worksheets(0), Worksheets(1), or, Sheet(0), Sheet(1)... Where 0, 1 are the tab/index positions.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, you have a few options.

### 1. Use a Constant

You can declare a constant at the top of your code, then you only need to make a change in the constant for it to affect every point where the constant is used. Rather than using:

```
Set shtSheet = sheets("Sheet1")
```

You could use:

```
Set shtSheet = Sheets(csSource)
```

throughout.

Declare a constant using `Const <name> as <type> = <value>`

```
Sub WorksheetVar()
    Const csSheetName As String = "Test"
    
    Sheets(csSheetName).Range("A1").Value = 1
    Sheets(csSheetName).Range("A2").Value = 2
    Sheets(csSheetName).Range("A3").Value = 3
End Sub
```

It doesn't get away from needing to set the value in the code, but it does allow you to update it more easily, rather than hunting through the code for all places the name is used.

### 2. Use Index numbers

Every worksheet has a number as well as a name, normally the position of the worksheet in the tabs. This will remain the same even if the sheet name is changed, but it will change if the tab order is changed.

### 3. Use a variable

You can get a variable from a cell, another macro, an input box, etc. You can use this to pass the worksheet's name to your code.

### 4. Use the sheet's object name

Independent of the worksheet's displayed name, every sheet has an object name, normally the name it had when it was first created. If you look at the project explorer on the left, you'll see that each sheet is listed as something like 'Sheet1 (Sheet1)'. If you changed the name of Sheet1 to Test, you'd see `Sheet1 (Test)`. You can use that unchanging object name to reference the sheet as needed, just as if it were a variable.

```
Sub Sheetname()
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 1
    Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = 2
End Sub
```

Personally I don't like this method, as it's easy to get confused about which sheet is which, but it's certainly an option for you.